# Why does the Javascript tag onclick doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute an on-click event. But when I click it - nothing shows. How to set correct on click listener for a link with javascript file?

```js
$('a#askCall').click(function(){
   alert("!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="askCall">Call me maybe</a>
```

### UPDATE:

Okay, but correct variant does not work for me too..

Comment: `.click()(`…`)` is the wrong syntax.

Comment: A quick look at error thrown in your browser console would tell you there is a syntax error. At least check those errors before asking here

Comment: @charlietfl A TypeError, not a SyntaxError, because this is still syntactically correct.

Comment: @Xufox yeah..I guess it is... is an IIFE after a click trigger...didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Include [**`jQuery`**](http://jquery.com/) library
- Syntax for `.click` is [**`jQueryElement.click( handler )`**](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
$('a#askCall').click(function() {
  alert("!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="askCall">Call me maybe</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works here when running snippet, but doesn't work in my jsp..

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev *"doesn't work in my jsp"* ... probably forgot to wrap in a document.ready handler or have errors in your console